# Play Framework 1.2.4 : Checking for the existence of specific errors

Tags: validation, playframework

I'm trying to display a generic error message when validation fails on certain fields, and more specific messages when other fields fail. However, I haven't been able to figure out a way to check for the existence of multiple errors by their keys.

I know that I can check for a single error with `#{ifError 'key'}` and I can check for multiple errors with `#{ifErrors}`, but how do I check for multiple error keys, something like `#{if (error 'keyA' || error 'keyB')}`? Multiple if statements won't work, as I would like the generic message displayed only once if certain errors are present.

What I'm trying to do is shown in the below snippet:

```
<!-- Only if there's an error on the 'specific' field will this div 
     be populated. -->
<div class="specificError">#{error 'specific' /}</div>

<!-- If there are other errors, display a generic error message.
     This if statement won't compile but shows what I want to do. -->
#{if (error 'fieldA' || error 'fieldB')}
    <div class="genericValidateError">&{'error.validation'}</div>
#{/if}
```

All suggestions are welcome, including those proposing alternative validation methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the validation object to check the fields directly as follow

```
#{if play.data.validation.Validation.current().hasError("fieldA") || 
     play.data.validation.Validation.current().hasError("fieldB") }

   <div class="genericValidateError">&{'error.validation'}</div>
#{/if}
```

Comment: I couldn't find an example in the documentation, but your suggestion did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best way to do it is creating your own FastTag. At least I think it is a better alternative (easy to test and reuse in different views). You can see how to create your own fast tags here: [custom java tags](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/templates#fasttags).